# Why doesn't C++ have a built in function to round to specific number of decimal places?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program in which I need to analyse the impact of rounding off on the result. The algorithm shall be implemented as fixed-point math eventually.

In my program I need to see what impact it has if I round off certain part of the calculation to 4, 3, 2, 1 decimal places and also integer. However, I found that C++ contains the round() method but this only gives integer result.

How is it that, C++ does not contain a way to round to specific number of decimal places that is built into it?

I found this from somewhere on the internet:

```
double round_up(double value, int decimal_places) {
    const double multiplier = std::pow(10.0, decimal_places);
    return std::ceil(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

But why should this be required, C++ is supposed to have a built in method to do this!

EDIT:

I am creating a design for FPGA implementation. The design shall be written in SystemVerilog. I want to investigate how many digits after decimal I should use for the fixed point maths. Yes, I am designing an actual ALU for discrete cosine transform IN HARDWARE. I could go into ASIC later i.e on silicon. I want to see how many digits I should have after decimal that is a reasonable trade-off for area vs accuracy. This is why I wrote a C++ program to investigate this. However, it seems that this was a false idea all along.

Comment: `ceil` doesn't round values.

Comment: *C++ is supposed to have a built in method* Who supposed that? Have you made a proposal for that?

Comment: Because there is no such thing as rounding a double to a specific number of decimal places. Doubles don’t have decimal places. They have binary places, and the two are incommensurable.

Comment: NB Your code doesn't work. Proof [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java/12684082#12684082).

Comment: @AhmedAEK No such proposal will be entertained, and you can't roll your own, for reasons already stated above.

Comment: @user207421 at least he will figure out how complicated it might be if he tries to write a proposal.

Comment: @AhmedAEK It's not 'complex'. It's impossible. From first principles. No attempt required.

Comment: Yes, having 0.25 that is 0.01b you cant round it to 0.3 that is 0.01001100110011b... that is not exaclty equal to 0.3.

Comment: You might want to consider the fact that any floating point type with a binary (base-2) significand [which, in the real world, describes near all floating point types] CANNOT exactly represent a decimal value of `0.1` (or any powers of it, such as `0.01`, `0.001`, ....).  Given that fact, how would you expect rounding to three decimal places to work if the decimal rounding would produce a value with fractional part `0.001`?

Comment: The question is not 'opinion-based'. It is fallacious.

Comment: *The algorithm shall be implemented as fixed-point math eventually.* -- There is really no "eventually" (IMO).  You either should implement using fixed point *now*, or use a class that handles fixed point.  Another approach is to rewrite your algorithm with the full knowledge that you are working with a binary computing machine, thus prone to round-off error/issues.  Many textbook algorithms have been (re)written taking this fact into account.

Comment: I am creating a design for FPGA implementation. The design shall be written in SystemVerilog. I want to investigate how many digits after decimal I should use for the fixed point maths. Yes, I am designing an actual ALU for discrete cosine transform. I want to see how many digits I should have after decimal that is a reasonable trade-off for area vs accuracy. This is why I wrote a C++ program to investigate this. However, it seems that this was a false idea all along.